# My .Include statement doing INNER JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN (EF Core 3.1)

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I have seen that basically I need to make my navigational property foreign key nullable. I do this, but it still does an inner join.

Here is the Menu table that is trying to join to Organizations. Note that MenuId is actually the same value as the OrgId in the Organizations table.

```
public partial class Menus
{
    [ForeignKey(nameof(Organizations))] 
    public int? MenuId { get; set; } //This is what I made nullable, but it still does an inner join
    public string MenuXml { get; set; }

    public Organizations Organizations { get; set; }
}
```

For reference, here is a simplified version of my Organizations model:

```
public partial class Organizations
{
    [Key]
    public int? OrgId { get; set; } //Also made this nullable, but I don't think I have to

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(70)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This is my .Include statement that I want to be a left join, but it is doing inner join. There are MenuId records which do not have a corresponding OrgId in the Organization table:

```
var listForView = menus.AsNoTracking().Include(menus => menus.Organizations);
```

Sounds simple. Other examples on Google and SO say that it will be a left join if I make the foreign key a nullable type, but it isn't changing the query for me.

Comment: Have you left out some attributes / fluent config? If `MenuId` is PK, it won;t be treated as nullable even if you use nullable type (primary / alternate keys are non nullable by definition). Also even if you somehow map it as nullable (which you can't if it is a key), that won't solve solve the "MenuId records which do not have a corresponding OrgId in the Organization table" because only null values are supposed to not have corresponding record, i.e. the expectation is  physical enforced relational database relationship.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So, I guess I get it that I have bad data in the database (reference to a row of Organizations that doesn't exist). The database is not mine so I can't control that. However, I know that when I write a LEFT JOIN in SQL I can get the result that I want. There has to be a way in EF Core to do this, no? What you say makes sense that I cant have the Key on a table be nullable, so MenuId cannot be nullable.

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot use EF automatic join services with such model, so you have to resort to manual joins - something we discourage with EF, but here it is the only way.

Comment: I can accept that as an answer. If there isn't a way to do it then so be it. I will come up with a workaround. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs very well with me. The generated sql statement is leftjoin instead of innerjoin. I wonder if you have a problem with the configuration, here is my code:
Menus class:

```
public partial class Menus
    {

        [ForeignKey(nameof(Organizations))]
        public int? MenuId { get; set; } 
        public string MenuXml { get; set; }

        public Organizations Organizations { get; set; }

    }
```

Organizations class:

```
public partial class Organizations
{
    [Key]
    public int OrgId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(70)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Your context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Menus>().HasNoKey();
```

and

```
 public DbSet<Menus> Menus { get; set; }
 public DbSet<Organizations> Organizations { get; set; }
```

Linq:

```
var listForView =context.Menus.AsNoTracking().Include(menus => menus.Organizations).ToList();
```

Result display:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkEaO.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so i resolved it by removing the call to the IsRequired() method in the Fluent API.